# matrix inside a matrix in R works in console but fails in terminal

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, terminal, console

This code segment creates train as a subset of matrix x, and it is still a matrix. What I don't understand is why using it to index the x matrix in the cv.glmnet statement in the segment below executes without error in RStudio with R4.2.2. However if I run the code in the terminal, then I would get this error message: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'drop': only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
Calls: cv.glmnet ... [ -> [.factor -> NextMethod -> .handleSimpleError -> h
Execution halted

```
library(ISLR2)
library(glmnet)
x <- model.matrix(Purchase~., OJ)[,-1]
y <- OJ$Purchase
trainIndex <- sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)*0.8)
train <- x[trainIndex,]
grid = 10^seq(-2, 4,length=200)
Model = cv.glmnet(x[train, ], y[train], alpha = 1, lambda = grid, family = "binomial", nfolds = 12)
```

I expected the code to produce an execution error, because a matrix (train) was used to index the rows of a matrix (x). However it only produced an execution error in the terminal not the console. I really just want an explanation.

Comment: Actually, the error is complaining about `y[train]`. While it is not illegal to use matrices as subscripts, it _is_ illegal to mix positive and negative subscripts. I suspect that in RStudio you are running R >= 4.2.0, while in Terminal you are running R < 4.2.0. (R 4.2.0 fixed a bug affecting this specific behaviour.) Can you check with `R.version` or `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce the error in Terminal running R 4.3.0.